# Seeking articles on kippa styles

Tags: books-generally, kippa-yarmulka

I've noticed that the style of kippa seems to be an "identity marker" for the "type" of Jew one is.

For example, it seems yeshivish boys wear only plain black kippot. More "modern" young kids seem to be interested in colors and may wear ones with designs or their name on it. Older men may wear a knit kippah. Conservative / Reform shuls tend to use silk / satin "domed" kippot.

Are there any published an online article or hard-copy book / article, etc. that has studied kippa styles?

If you find something, please post as an answer, rather than a comment.

Comment: Haven't found any yet, but this is related and super-interesting https://www.google.com/patents/US20150181969

Comment: I stopped wearing kippot serugot because they're expensive here (at least outside of NYC) and difficult to clean. I now wear a small dark navy velvet (four part) one which goes well with my tallis (which also has navy stripes)

Comment: I'm not sure this is on topic. It doesn't seem that these relate to different views of propriety. Rather, by all indications, this is sociological; people want to identify with one group or another. Questions of sociology seem like Jews; not Judaism.

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/Cultural-History-Jewish-Dress-Culture/dp/1847882862

Comment: @mevaqesh Wearing a Kippa is an expression of Judaism. Sociology of kippot is sociology of Judaism. Sociology of Judaism, like history of Judaism, is on-topic.

Answer (score 3):

You might enjoy the following

- The Forward has [a review](https://forward.com/articles/213738/show-me-your-yarmulke/) of different kippa styles with explanations of who wears what
- The Pew Research Center has [a study](http://www.pewresearch.org/fact-tank/2016/04/20/what-different-styles-of-head-coverings-say-about-israeli-jewish-men/) on how kippa styles relate to observance in Israel (with a larger data set [here](http://assets.pewresearch.org/wp-content/uploads/sites/12/2016/04/FT_16.4.20.Kippa_.Topline.pdf))